# SVN on Windows: how to make it English

Tags: svn, language, locale

I'm using SVN 1.7.2 binaries on my German Windows XP machine. What I need to do to make it output text in English instead of German?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
export LANG=C
export LC_MESSAGES=C
```

It tells svn not to translate any message (english being the default). Alternatively, you can force it to english by using:

```
export LANG=en_US
export LC_MESSAGES=en_US
```

Comment: Mike is using Windows - therefore "export" will not work. Anyway setting _LANG=en_US_ works.

Comment: I assumed he used svn under Cygwin, which supports "export".

Comment: Setting `LC_MESSAGES` is not necessary if it was not set already; `LANG` is enough.

Comment: Using cmder on Win 7: `set LANG=C`