# Mercurial: what has influence on the language used for output

Tags: language, mercurial, i18n

Based on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/369517/svn-on-windows-how-to-make-it-english) - what setting is responsible for the language Mercurial (hg.exe) uses to display output? I remember I saw German output, but now see English one. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592664/hg-how-do-i-change-the-language-of-my-mercurialhg-installation-macos

Depending on the OS, it seems to be `LANG` or `LANGUAGE`.

There is a mention of `export LANGUAGE` here on mercurial site: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TranslatingMercurial

Comment: Strange thing: when I push to a locally available remote repository, I'm seeing English text, but when I push to a really remote repository, I'm seeing German text. It looks like the text is coming from the server, not the local Hg instance.